# Replace all string types in Python Pandas Data Frame with a 1

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe

This is an oddly specific question but

if I have a pandas data frame that looks like:

```
...
8                                                        0
9                                                        0
10                                                       0
11                                                       0
12                                                       0
13                                                    Dogs
14                                                    Cats
...
```

And I need it to see all the string types and change them to a 1, so:

```
...
8                                                        0
9                                                        0
10                                                       0
11                                                       0
12                                                       0
13                                                       1
14                                                       1
...
```

Is there a way maybe to get df.replace() to see the string types?

Thanks!

Comment: Are all other numeric values valid, i.e. you don't have `NaN` already anywhere? if not then you can do `df['col'] = pd.to_numeric(df['col'], errors='coerce').fillna(1).astype(int)`

Comment: Yep that totally worked, thanks EdChum!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So long as the other values in your column are all valid numeric values and there are no `NaN` values already, you can use [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html#pandas.to_numeric) to force the string values into a numeric value, in this case `NaN`.

You can then replace `NaN` with `1`, but because of the introduction of `NaN`, the `dtype` is changed to `float` so we need to case the `dtype` to `int` using [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html):

```
In [6]:    
# read the data into our df
import pandas as pd
import io
​
t="""8                                                        0
9                                                        0
10                                                       0
11                                                       0
12                                                       0
13                                                    Dogs
14                                                    Cats"""
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t), delim_whitespace=True, header=None)
df

Out[6]:
    0     1
0   8     0
1   9     0
2  10     0
3  11     0
4  12     0
5  13  Dogs
6  14  Cats
```

Now convert the strings, replace them with `1` and cast the Series dtype back to int:

```
In [7]:
df[1] = pd.to_numeric(df[1], errors='coerce').fillna(1).astype(int)
df

Out[7]:
    0  1
0   8  0
1   9  0
2  10  0
3  11  0
4  12  0
5  13  1
6  14  1
```